# Postgresql howto dynamically change parameter value

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Is it possible to dynamically set param of numeric() ? eg:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE somefunction() RETURNS numeric AS  
DECLARE    
f numeric;
x integer;  
BEGIN
    x := 2;
    SELECT INTO f CAST(something AS numeric(12, x));
    RETURN f;
END;
```

So, I don't need to use CASE inside my plpgsql function if possible :)  Tried everything, but it does not work, cast expects constant.  Thanks:)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here. Why do you even need a function for that? Was it just an example? Where does `something` comes from? What is it supposed to be?

Comment: Additionally: it should be: `f := cast(...)`

Comment: something is eg CAST(SELECT CAST(tb.price/tb.price2 AS numeric(12,4)), sometimes I need result casted as numeric(12,2), sometimes as numeric(12,4) or even numeric(12,6). EDIT: Of course f := CAST(f AS numeric(12,x)) instead of casting inside query.... but aynway, is it possible to set dynamically number of decimal places or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Dynamic query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.somefunction(something numeric)
 RETURNS numeric
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
f numeric;
x integer;
BEGIN
    x := 2;
    EXECUTE 'SELECT  CAST($1 AS numeric(12, ' || x ||'))' INTO f USING something;
    RETURN f;
END;
$function$
;

select somefunction(126.787);
 somefunction 
--------------
       126.79
```

Alternate where you pass in the scale:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.somefunction(something numeric, scale integer)
 RETURNS numeric
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE    
f numeric;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'SELECT  CAST($1 AS numeric(12, ' || scale ||'))' INTO f USING something;
    RETURN f;
END;
$function$
;

select somefunction(126.787,2);
 somefunction 
--------------
       126.79
(1 row)

select somefunction(126.787,1);
 somefunction 
--------------
        126.8
```

Comment: Thanks :) That's exactly what I want :)))